# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. getting in .net framework 4.51

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have below code in .net 4.5.1. Rest response always giving me error "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly". If i place same code in a seperate project it's working fine. What is wrong here??

```
  var client = new RestClient("url");
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;               
                    client.Timeout = -1;
                    Login login = new Login { UserName = "user", PassWord = "password" };
                    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login), ParameterType.RequestBody);
                    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                    if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                    {
                        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoginResponse>>(response.Content);
                        return list.FirstOrDefault().Token;
                    }
```

Comment: Why are you using 4.5.1? All supported Windows OSs come with far newer versions. And given that 1) almost all sites use HTTPS 2) almost all sites use TLS1.2 and 3) 4.5.1 doesn't use TLS1.2 by default, I'd expect most public sites to reject connections

Comment: The attempt to turn off certificate validation suggests you already had problems with SSL and tried to cover them up instead of solving them. This doesn't affect the TLS version used though. The best solution would be to upgrade to at least .NET 4.6.2, which uses automatically the best available TLS version to connect. All supported Windows and Windows Server versions come with .NET 4.6.2. In unsupported OSs and old .NET versions like 4.5.1 you can use `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` to use TLS1.2